# Getting information according to conditions in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to create SP That runs according to few conditions:
I have 2 Tables that I Joined between them in order to get the information that I need:
(I'm sending as a param @LocaitonID)

Table 1 "Devices"

```
DeviceID
Device Serial
Model
Carrier
LocationID
Active
```

Table 2 "Locations"

```
PostID
LocationName
LocationID
```

Now the thing is to bring the information if:

1. LocationID=@LocationID,Active=True
2. Active = false
3. LocationID=0,Active=false
4. LocationID=@LocationID,Active=false

How can I do it with if statement????
return

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDeviceInfo] @LocationID int = NULL AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT GAD.DeviceID,
       GAL.PostID,
       GAD.DeviceSerial,
       GAD.Model,
       GAD.Carrier,
       GAD.PhoneNumber,
       GAD.LocalName,
       GAD.Notes,
       GAD.Created
FROM GuardAppDevices AS GAD
JOIN GuardAppLocations AS GAL ON GAD.LocationID=GAL.LocationID
WHERE (@LocationID = GAD.LocationID
       OR @LocationID IS NULL)
  AND GAD.Active=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the entire situation, but these criteria :

1. LocationID=@LocationID,Active=True
2. Active = false
3. LocationID=0,Active=false
4. LocationID=@LocationID,Active=false

can be written as SQL `WHERE` clause as follow :

```
.....
WHERE (LocationID = @LocationID AND Active = 1)
       OR (Active = 0)
       OR (LocationID = 0 AND Active = 0)
       OR (LocationID = @LocationID AND Active = 0)
```

note that criteria no.1 and no.4 can be written as single criteria : `LocationID=@LocationID`, assuming that Active field can only contains value of either true or false.

Comment: I have on my aspx page RadComboBox with Values once the user is selecting something its going to the SP that I'm creating right now and bring all the information accroding to what he selected lets say if he selected on the RCB the Value 1 its going to the SP and finding the condition number 1 and bring all the information for that can I still do it with Where clause?

Comment: there is any other way to do it with If statement?

Comment: I don't have idea to do it with `if` statement, I guess there is a way but it won't be easy way. TSQL is not designed like procedural programming language where you loop through and check with if statement row by row.